# Does anyone know why my heroku app doesn't access any of the data from my seeds.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I recently deployed an app to heroku but for some reason the heroku app doesn't access any of the seed data from the seed.rb file but when I run the app locally the data shows up just fine. Would love assistance

Comment: Why you tagged this as `react` when it's clearly a problem with `ruby`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the rails task as follows:

```
heroku run rails db:seed -a name_of_your_heroku_app
```

You may need to do heroku login first.

Comment: Maybe he does even need to provide the -a name_of_heroku_app. After login, heroku will probably know which app it belongs to (unless there are more than one heroku configured to the same project).